# How to translate the name of days of the week and months in Django calendar

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask how can I change the name of the days of the week and month from the original English to e.g. Polish in the calendar rendered in Django

I tried to find a solution in changing the language in the settings but nothing works
I also tried to use LocalHTMLCalendar but it didn't work

this is my utlis.py file

```
class Calendar(LocaleHTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        translation.activate('pl')
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
        d = ''
        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
            print()
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

and this is my views.py file

```
def get_date(req_day):
    translation.activate('pl')

    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.today()


def prev_month(d):
    first = d.replace(day=1)
    prev_month = first - timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(prev_month.year) + '-' + str(prev_month.month)
    return month


def next_month(d):
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(d.year, d.month)[1]
    last = d.replace(day=days_in_month)
    next_month = last + timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(next_month.year) + '-' + str(next_month.month)
    return month


class CalendarView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = 'signup'
    model = Event
    template_name = 'sytoapp/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        print(d.month)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
```

I would appreciate any hints

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can take the working example below and adapt the principle to your actual case. Notice the _ in front of every string required for translation.

However, even with my example, this involves some further work:

- when happy with your .py code, you have to generate the .po file for it (i.e. [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) editable translation file for the target language); this can be generated with `gettext -o yourfile.po yourfile.py` by using gettext from gettext tools (note: on my local system, the name I gave for this example file is 'test_i18n.py'; this name (but without the extension) is also specified explicitly in the `language = gettext.translation('test_l10n', locale_path, [current_locale]` line in my code below; the name specified in this line must match the name of the actual <del>.py program file</del> .mo compiled language file generated further in this localization process (the fourth bullet down here);
- a `"Language: xx\n"` line must be inserted into the header block of the .po file (say, after the `"Language-Team: etc."` line), where xx is the target language ID (which in your case is pl);
- translate the .po entries using, for example, [Poedit](https://www.poedit.net) or [Gtranslator](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gtranslator);
- when happy with your translation, you have to generate the .mo file (i.e. compiled translation file) from the .po file; Poedit will do this automatically, but this can be generated also with `msgfmt yourfile.po -o yourfile.mo` by using msgfmt from gettext tools;
- put (copy or move) the generated .mo file to a locale path relative to your code; for example, on same location as the .py program, a `/locale/xx/LC_MESSAGES/` path must exist (or be generated) with the .mo file inside it (notes: the 'xx' is the target language ID and the .mo filename must match the name <del>of the main .py program file</del> specified explicitly in the `language = gettext.translation('test_l10n', locale_path, [current_locale]` line);
- run the program, it should display the localized name from now.

**Later edit:** matter of fact, the name of the .mo file inside the `/locale/xx/LC_MESSAGES/` path must match the name from the `language = gettext.translation('test_l10n', locale_path, [current_locale]` line in my code below, both of which can be chosen independently of the name of the .py file itself. Sorry if I've created confusion before.

This is my example file test_l10n.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import datetime
import locale
import gettext

##

class l10nTest(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def Main(self):
        self.get_datetime = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.weekday_now = self.get_datetime.weekday()
        self.temp = self.weekday_now + 1
        self.dayl = self.DayOfWeekLiteral(str(self.temp))

        print (_("Today is %s") % self.dayl)

    def DayOfWeekLiteral(self, dday):
        self.dday = dday
        if int(self.dday) == 1:
            self.dayl = _("Monday")
        if int(self.dday) == 2:
            self.dayl = _("Tuesday")
        if int(self.dday) == 3:
            self.dayl = _("Wednesday")
        if int(self.dday) == 4:
            self.dayl = _("Thursday")
        if int(self.dday) == 5:
            self.dayl = _("Friday")
        if int(self.dday) == 6:
            self.dayl = _("Saturday")
        if int(self.dday) == 7:
            self.dayl = _("Sunday")
        return self.dayl

##

if __name__ == "__main__":

    current_locale, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()
    # or it can be forced explicitly by uncomment the line below
#    current_locale = "pl"
    locale_path = './locale/'
    language = gettext.translation('test_l10n', locale_path, [current_locale])
    language.install()

    app = l10nTest(0)
    app.Main()
```

And this is my test_l10n.po file (in my case, for Romanian):

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2021-02-02 22:08+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2021-02-02 22:09+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: ro\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.4.2\n"

#: test_l10n.py:20
#, python-format
msgid "Today is %s"
msgstr "Azi este %s"

#: test_l10n.py:25
msgid "Monday"
msgstr "luni"

#: test_l10n.py:27
msgid "Tuesday"
msgstr "marți"

#: test_l10n.py:29
msgid "Wednesday"
msgstr "miercuri"

#: test_l10n.py:31
msgid "Thursday"
msgstr "joi"

#: test_l10n.py:33
msgid "Friday"
msgstr "vineri"

#: test_l10n.py:35
msgid "Saturday"
msgstr "sâmbătă"

#: test_l10n.py:37
msgid "Sunday"
msgstr "duminică"
```

**Later edit:** I forgot to mention: running the above example on my system (Windows 10, with the system locale set to Romanian), it gives:

(at the time I posted this answer)

```
Azi este marți
```

(at the time I added this later edit, which is the next day already in terms of local time)

```
Azi este miercuri
```